# How do I access FK values ​from view?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, model-view-controller

I have two models. How do I access FK values ​​from view or how should I go about it? HTML page nothing appears.

Model 1:

```
    public class Ogrenci
{
    public int OgrenciID { get; set; }
    public int OgrenciNumarasi { get; set; }
    public string Ad { get; set; }
    public string Soyad { get; set; }
    public string Bolum { get; set; }
    public short Sinif { get; set; }
    public string Yetenekler { get; set; }
    public string Sifre { get; set; }

    public List<Proje> Projeler { get; set; }
}
```

Model 2:

```
    public class Proje
{
    public int ProjeID { get; set; }
    public string ProjeAdi { get; set; }
    public string Aciklama { get; set; }
    public DateTime EklenmeTarihi { get; set; }

    public int OgrenciID { get; set; }
    public Ogrenci Ogrenci { get; set; }

}
```

Controller:

```
        public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View(db.Projeler.ToList());
    }
```

View:

```
@model IEnumerable<DonemProjesi.Models.Proje>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}
@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Ogrenci.Ad)    //the problem is here
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to specify the related objects to be include in the query results:

```cs
 return View(db.Projeler.Include(o => o.Ogrenci).ToList());
```

See [Loading Related Entities](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/querying/related-data).

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
     public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View(db.Ogrenci.Include(o => o.Projeler).FirstOrDefault());
    }

@model DonemProjesi.Models.Ogrenci

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

@Html.DisplayFor(m => m.Ad)  

@for (int i = 0; i < Model.Projeler.Count; i+=1)
{
 @Html.DisplayFor(model =>model.Projeler[i].ProjeAdi)
}
```

or maybe you mean this

```
   public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View(db.Projeler.Include(o => o.Ogrenci).ToList());
    }

@model IEnumerable<DonemProjesi.Models.Proje>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}
@for (int i = 0; i < Model.Count; i+=1)
{
@Html.DisplayFor(model =>model[i].ProjeAdi)
 @Html.DisplayFor(model => model[i].Ogrenci.Ad)
}
```